# JPA Copy Items Between 2 Different Schemas and Sessions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I thought I'd share my insights for whom it may concern to copy entities between 2 different schemas (each is handle by its own dataSource/entityManager/Session).

In my case, the target schema may or may not have the item, so it may be either an insert or an update. 
Also, although the id is auto generated, I'd like to keep the source id (avoiding the target schema to generate its own id).

Most of the hard work, was been handled by the: 
    Session.replicate(sourceEntity, ReplicationMode.OVERWRITE)

However, the challenges with I encounter were:

1. The ***detach()*** method must be invoked in order to avoid getting this error: *org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions*
2. When the existing item were been replicated, if the newer equivalent source item had been removed from some of its association children, the target entity still kept the obsolete children as well - so I removed the old target entity before replicating the source.
3. I had another issue with the auto-generated Id. Although one would expect that replicate method would transfer the existing Id, this was not the case, and a new Id were always been generated. I solve this issue by replacing the sessionFactory's DefaultReplicateEventListener with a custom one, which demand the Id to be taken from the source entity.

The replica is taken care by this code:

```
MyEntity sourceEntity = sourceEntityManager.find(MyEntity.class, sourceEntity.getId());
sourceEntityManager.detach(sourceEntity);
Session hibernateSession = 
targetEntityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
hibernateSession.replicate(sourceEntity, ReplicationMode.OVERWRITE);
```

The clean replica was assisted by first removing the existing entity before replicating it :

```
MyEntity existingEntity = 
targetEntityManager.find(MealDescription.class, sourceEntity.getId())
targetEntityManager.remove(existingMeal);
```

Replacing the default replicate listener (DefaultReplicateEventListener), by overriding the class and replacing the listener:

```
public static class IdPreservingReplicateEventListener extends DefaultReplicateEventListener implements Loggable {
    @Override
    protected Serializable performSaveOrReplicate(Object entity, EntityKey key, EntityPersister persister, boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, EventSource source, boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess){
        if (key == null) {
            Serializable id = persister.getIdentifier( entity, source );
            key = source.generateEntityKey( id, persister );
            useIdentityColumn = false;
        }

        return super.performSaveOrReplicate(entity, key, persister, useIdentityColumn, anything, source, true);
    }
}
```

And replacing it to the sessionFactory:

```
EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.REPLICATE).clear();
registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.REPLICATE).appendListener(new IdPreservingReplicateEventListener());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to detach it from SourceEntityManager and merge it to TargetEntityManager:

```
final MyEntity sourceEntity = sourceEntityManager.find(MyEntity.class, sourceEntity.getId());
sourceEntityManager.detach(sourceEntity);
targetEntityManager.merge(sourceEntity);
```

For more information see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45734649/7634201

Comment: The detach is part of the solution, but the merge fails.
It seems that I have issue with persisting some of the associated collection
Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my question according to my later insights